# How to get array keys in dictionary using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I have this angular Dictionary as example:

```
{
   ARRAY1: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
   ARRAY2: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
   ARRAY3: [{...}, {...}]
   ARRAY4: [{...}]
}
```

I would like to display in HTML page all array keys from dictionary.

I tried did it, but not working.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list| keyvalue">
    <span>{{item.key}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object structure is incorrect, I update it and use pipe `keyvalue` it still worked.

Stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-key-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly,
just you are missing `,` at the end of each `ARRAY` in the object

So update your object as

```
{
   ARRAY1: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
   ARRAY2: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
   ARRAY3: [{...}, {...}],
   ARRAY4: [{...}]
}
```